Is this some type of tile glue
I recently removed a bunch of ceramic tile from my slab concrete floor. I also removed most, if not all, of the tile thinset. However, there is still some type of material on the floor that is a bit difficult to remove. I'm able to remove it with a floor scraper but the razor blade dulls very fast and it takes a lot of time and effort to remove it. Based on the attached photos, can anyone identify what the material is and best way to remove it. I'm assuming it is some type of glue. Should I buy a diamabrush and try that? End goal is to install LVP.
Thanks







That looks to be a glue that is used to glue down an uncoupling membrane.
Unfortunately, it takes a lot of scraping or grinding to get off.  I have used a heavy brush in a drill, but I had only about 3 square feet to remove.
A side note: LVP is very forgiving to minor chips and bumps. with the attached padding that most all LVP has, minor floor imperfections are not noticeable.  If what you have on the floor is the thickness of a dime or less it won't matter.

Yeah, I'm wondering if one could adapt a wire brush to a floor polisher or something.  Make sure to wear the appropriate PPE!
